# ElasticSearch match query multiple terms PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch, querydsl

I am trying to construct must query on multiple terms, the array looks like this:

```
$params = [
'body' => [
    'query' => [
        "bool" => [
            "must" => [
                "terms" => [
                    "categories" => [
                        "Seating",
                    ],
                ],
                "terms" => [
                    "attributes.Color" => [
                        "Black",
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            "filter" => [
                "range" => [
                    "price" => [
                        "gte" => 39,
                        "lte" => 2999,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'from' => 0,
    'size' => 3,
],
];
```

Which is represented in JSON like this:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "terms": {
                "attributes.Color": ["Black"]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "range": {
                "price": {
                    "gte": "39",
                    "lte": "2999"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"from": 0,
"size": 3
}
```

The problem is, JSON objects are represented as arrays in PHP so if I setup key for one array, it is rewritten. Do you have any idea on how to create multiple terms query in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not group same key values? like this "terms" => [
                    "categories" => [
                        "Seating"
                    ],
 "attributes.Color" => [
                        "Black"
                    ]
                ],

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an additional array to enclose all your `terms` queries

```
$params = [
'body' => [
    'query' => [
        "bool" => [
            "must" => [
              [
                "terms" => [
                    "categories" => [
                        "Seating",
                    ],
                ]
              ],
              [
                "terms" => [
                    "attributes.Color" => [
                        "Black",
                    ],
                ]
              ]
            ],
            "filter" => [
                "range" => [
                    "price" => [
                        "gte" => 39,
                        "lte" => 2999,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'from' => 0,
    'size' => 3,
],
];
```